# Resolve a system using Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: group-theory

I have the following system:
 $x  \equiv 3 \mod 26$  and 
 $x  \equiv 7 \mod 41$

How can we solve it using Chinese remainder theorem. Any guidelines ?
Many thanks

Comment: Write $x=26y+3$ and put that into the second congruence.

Comment: Why the -1 ? please add more info and be specific !

Comment: @MarwanB you probably got (-1) because you didn't include in the question any information about what you tried, and also adding the theorem in the question can be helpful

Comment: I guess the only reasonable answer is *by applying the Chinese remainder theorem*. Have you already managed to solve similar problems?

Answer (score 2):

The general method consists in finding first a *Bézout's relation* between $26$ and $41$, $\;26\,u+41\,v=1,\; u,v \in\mathbf Z$ with the *extended Euclidean algorithm*.

Then, you have a formula for the solutions:
$$x\equiv7\cdot 26\,u+3\cdot41\,v\mod 26\cdot41.$$

You should find $\; x\equiv -75\mod 1066$.

Answer (score 1):

you can write $$x=3+26m,x=7+41n$$ so we get
$$26m-41n=4$$ with $$m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$$ solving this Diophantine equation we get
$$m=348+41k,n=24+26k$$

Comment: Is that CRT?....

Comment: we do not need that, why do you ask me knowing the answer?

Comment: Actually I need that because I am asked to use CRT. How did you solve the Diophantine? did you use a solver ? Thanks

Comment: i solved it with remainder calculus